# PHP array_map multiple parameters not working How to resolve?

Tags: php

In my code below ***GST*** and ***Amount*** are printing properly but ***Discount*** is not printing the result. Why is ***Discount*** not printing? How can I solve this issue?

```
$GST = Array ( [0] => 18 );
$Amount = Array ( [0] => 25000 );
$Discount = Array ( [0] => 10 );
array_map( 
    function($GST, $Amount, $Discount){ 
        echo ' GST: '.$GST.' Amount: '.$Amount.' Discount: '.$Discount.'<br>';
        echo 'Discount: '.(($Amount * $Discount) / 100).' Amount After Discount: '.($Amount - (($Amount * $Discount) / 100)).'<br>';
        echo 'GST: '.(($Amount - (($Amount * $Discount) / 100)) * $GST / 100).'<br>';
        //return ($Amount - (($Amount * $Discount) / 100)) * $GST / 100; 
    }, 
    !is_array($GST) ? [] : $GST, 
    !is_array($Amount) ? [] : $Amount, 
    !is_array($Discount) ? [] : $Discount 
)
```

Comment: Is that how you defined your arrays? That should throw parse errors. Btw, I tested your code and it works (after changing how you define the arrays). Here's a demo: https://3v4l.org/SqgJO

Comment: `$GST = Array ( [0] => 18 );` is not valid PHP

Answer (score 2):

A matter of redefining the arrays and you should be on your way of success. Code provided by user [**Magnus Eriksson**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2453432/magnus-eriksson).

```
$GST      = Array (18);
$Amount   = Array (25000);
$Discount = Array (10);
array_map( 
    function($GST, $Amount, $Discount){ 
        var_dump($GST, $Amount, $Discount);
        echo PHP_EOL;
        echo 'GST: '.$GST.' Amount: '.$Amount.' Discount: '.$Discount.PHP_EOL;
        echo 'Discount: '.(($Amount * $Discount) / 100).' Amount After Discount: '.($Amount - (($Amount * $Discount) / 100)).PHP_EOL;
        echo 'GST: '.(($Amount - (($Amount * $Discount) / 100)) * $GST / 100).PHP_EOL;
        //return ($Amount - (($Amount * $Discount) / 100)) * $GST / 100; 
    }, 
    !is_array($GST) ? [] : $GST, 
    !is_array($Amount) ? [] : $Amount, 
    !is_array($Discount) ? [] : $Discount 
);
```

Output:

> int(18)
>
> int(25000)
>
> int(10)
>
> GST: 18 Amount: 25000 Discount: 10
>
> Discount: 2500 Amount After Discount: 22500
>
> GST: 4050

Comment: You could at least give me a shout out if you're going to copy/paste my demo? :-p

Comment: When your comment was posted I wasn't finished yet pasting the code. As you see you are referenced;-) Also submitted an edit for the question itself to make it readable.

Comment: No worries.  :-)